# Views from app not updating/refreshing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, httpserver

Im using http-server, but the problem is that my views arent updating well, i already restarted the server, and takes very long to the browser update, is very annoying, online i already tried it, but when using http-server it gets this problem. Is there a better way rining a local server in nodejs

Comment: What have you tried? What are the errors? [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

Disable browser cache. It loads it and somehow it doesn't update when template is changed

Comment: @MBPP and you cleaned it. Can the template files depend on the server? I thought it just serves them in their newest versions.